# new app-id - OAuthException (#200) on post comment

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Since I created a new (Facebook) App last week, I get an `OAuthException` whenever I want to comment on a post.

> "(OAuthException) (#200) You do not have sufficient to permissions to perform this action".

With the old App, my application works fine.

Now I found out that Facebook has changed the login policy recently. I also found the following remark on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0:

> "If your app asks for more than than `public_profile`, `email` and `user_friends` it will require review by Facebook before your app can be used by people **other than the app's developers**".

So if I post with the same account with which I created the App, it should work, right? Only it doesn't...

*Remark*: if I use the new App with another Facebook-account, I have even less permissions (e.g. cannot access the account's pages). So I have more permissions if I use the same account, but still I cannot post!

I use Graph API via .NET Facebook-Client; my App is a native app (desktop app).

Could someone please tell me how to post with a new App? This is the main use-case of our application! Thank you very much!

---

Here is a screenshot of what I see instead of the login-screen when I use extended permission "publish_action" instead of "publish_stream"

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be able to post with your own account since you are the admin of the application. - since only the admins/developers/testers will be able to test the app with the publishing functionality before it gets approved by facebook.

If you still are not able to, you must have not granted the permissions to the app. Things to check-

1. You are using `publish_actions` and not `publish_stream`
2. Check in your [application settings](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications) whether or not you can see the publishing permission is granted for that app.

   [image]

   If not granted, go through the login process again and grant the publishing permission (may be by removing the app from settings and then authorizing again OR logout the app and then login again with `publish_actions`)

Comment: Thank you! I changed the extended permissions now from publish_stream to publish_action, but now instead of a login-screen I see "Success SICHERHEITSWARNUNG: Bitte behandle ...." (a security alert)

Extended permissions used:  "user_about_me,read_stream,publish_action,offline_access,read_mailbox,manage_pages,read_page_mailboxes"

Comment: Sure. Where do I best attach it? Not possible in a comment, is it?

Comment: have no account there. i edited my original question and added the screenshot there.

Comment: Your login flow isn't correct! I'm not really sure how are you doing it

Comment: We use FacebookOAuthClient (C#, Facebook.dll, from http://csharpsdk.org/). Here some lines of code, hope this is helpful:
 
oauthClient = new FacebookOAuthClient { AppId = appId };
...
loginParameters["response_type"] = "token";
loginParameters["display"] = "popup";
loginParameters["scope"] = extendedPermissions;
_loginUrl = oauthClient.GetLoginUrl(loginParameters);

Comment: This is the login-url: "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?response_type=token&display=popup&scope=user_about_me,read_stream,publish_action,offline_access,read_mailbox,manage_pages,read_page_mailboxes&client_id=***********&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html"

Comment: sorry, again without the http-part:

/dialog/oauth/?response_type=token&display=popup&scope=user_about_me,read_stream,publish_action,offline_access,read_mailbox,manage_pages,read_page_mailboxes&client_id=***********&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.htm

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved - it was a stupid typo: I wrote `publish_action` instead of `publish_actions` (should be plural)! Thanks again to CBroe who pointed it out in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28699623/login-security-warning-with-publish-action)!